# Why is return false and return true used after this inline event-handler?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<button onclick="alert('Hello'); return false;">Hello</button>
```

What is the return false part supposed to do? Also, what would return true do if it were there?

Comment: in this case, the return false won't change anything

Comment: @Grigor, yes it will if the button is inside a form since without it the button acts as a form submit button on any browser other than IE.

Comment: I know it will, but as I said, in this case its not in a form so it won't change anything.

Comment: Actually @Grigor, I found this example code inside a form element...

Comment: well I couldn't guess that it came from a form, I made a statement based on your given code my friend :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [default button type](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp) is `submit`, so `<button>` is the same as `<button type="submit">` (except on IE).  The `return false` stops the default button action so it will stop form submission from happening.

You can avoid that by defining the button type explicitly

```
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello');">Hello</button>
```

Comment: Never knew that. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 7):

The `return false` will disregard default behavior for the `onclick` event. So, for example, if you had a link:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" onclick="alert('Hello'); return false">Link<a>
```

when the user clicks on the link they'd get a popup but wouldn't actually go the target of the link.

Comment: Which is to do nothing anyway. `return false` really only makes sense with submit or reset buttons.

Comment: @nfechner or links, or anything else with default behavior for onclick.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context.

For example return true|false on a submit button either does or does not submit the form which you can use for form validation,  i.e. return false if the validation fails and prevent the form from submitting.

In many cases it will acheive nothing for example the button in your code example to my knowledge does nothing with the retirn value.